# Errors when passing JSON from PHP blade template to Laravel component

Tags: php, json, laravel

We have a Laravel 8 project.

In it, we have a Blade template, and from this Blade template we are including a Laravel component like this:

```
<x-key-figure-graph
    measure="IQ_TOTAL_REV"
    dividend-history="{{ json_encode($dividend_history) }}"
    show-last="10">
</x-key-figure-graph>
```

The `$dividend_history` is an associative array that looks like this:

```
['2002' => ['date' => '2002-06-30', 'IQ_CLOSEPRICE' => 27.35]],
['2003' => ['date' => '2003-06-30', 'IQ_CLOSEPRICE' => 33.81]],
...
```

I am doing `json_encode` on the array to transform it into a string so I can pass it as a prop to the `x-key-figure-graph` component.

Within the component is where problems arise. If I print out the passed prop:

```
{{ $dividendHistory }}
```

I get:

```
{&quot;2002&quot;:{&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2002-06-30&quot;,&quot;IQ_CLOSEPRICE&quot;:27.35 [...]
```

So this is a string with the quotes turned into their ASCII equivalents (`&quot;`). Doing json_decode on this string returns null, so it is not a valid JSON string.

How do I pass the prop as a valid decodable JSON?Back in the original Blade template (from which we include the  component, if I try to `dd()` the `$dividend_history` as returned by  the controller, everything looks ok:

```
array:21 [▼
  2002 => array:2 [▼
    "date" => "2002-06-30"
    "IQ_CLOSEPRICE" => 27.35
  ],
  ...
```

Comment: Yes, the issue is with the string. Try looking into the `$dividend_history` returned from your controller. Do a `dd()` to take a closer look at what's returned from your controller.

Comment: @sykez Added to the end of the question. The data returned by the controller looks alright to me.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a PHP problem, or a JS problem? If PHP prints invalid JSON, there's nothing JS can (and should!) do about this

Comment: @NicoHaase I've tried the 3 things listed at the end of the question. Is it even invalid JSON? It looks like the string is escaped when printed. The array looks alright.

Comment: @NicoHaase `json_decode` of the string return `null`  so I guess it's a PHP problem. The question remains how to fix it - in PHP then I suppose.

Comment: @NicoHaase I've been trying to pass the prop with or without quotes, with single and double quotes, nothing helps.

Comment: "So this is a string with the quotes turned into their ASCII equivalents" - have you tried to use https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#rendering-json?

Comment: @NicoHaase The problem seems to lie with passing the JSON string as a prop. The Js facade doesn't help as it takes an array as an argument.

Comment: @NicoHaase I will remove the unnecessary tags. Has nothing to do with Javascript apprently.

Comment: @NicoHaase Updated the question: the real question is how to pass the array as a valid json from blade to component.

Comment: "The Js facade doesn't help as it takes an array as an argument" - and what's the problem with that? As you stated in your question, the original input is an array?

Comment: @nicoHaase You're right. But I'm getting an error when I try to use the Js facade instead of `json_encode`: `class 'illuminate\support\js' not found`

Comment: Then you might want to check which version of Laravel you are using. Since v8.70.0, that class exists - the prior name was `JsString`, so maybe it works using that?

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm on version 8.0 and JsString also doesn't exist for some reason.

Comment: If you are really using v8.0.x, then you should upgrade that. The latest 8.0.x version is more than a year old, and Packagist lists four security advisories for that

Comment: Feel free to add all clarification to your question by editing it. It could help if others knew the **exact** version of Laravel you are using, to provide the proper solution that does not need more guessing about which feature is available, and which is not

Comment: If you have a fix at hand, why not post this as an answer? Maybe others  have the same problem in the future?

Comment: @NicoHaase I will, but maybe you could try finding the solution for sport since we spent so  much time here already. It's a "back to the basics" sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You had to pass `$dividendHistory` as a variables (es. `:prop`).
So, assuming you already encoded your data:

```
<x-key-figure-graph
  measure="IQ_TOTAL_REV"
  :dividend-history="$dividend_history"
  show-last="10">
</x-key-figure-graph>
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#passing-data-to-components